# HTML5 isogenic engine mouse cursor

Tags: html, cursor, mouse

I'm a newbie to HTML5 game, and I'd like to know how to change the mouse cursor when I point out an building on a tile?

I created tilemap, created a Shop class extending IgeEntity class.
Then I have created an object "MyShop" which is an instance of Shop class.
And finally,

```
MyShop.occupyTiles(3,3, 2,2);
```

I'd like to change my mouse cursor to my custom cursor (from file) when I point out the shop.

And is it possible to get the object under the cursor when I click the mouse?
I mean, when I click my shop, I'd like to show something.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of context missing here.

Comment: only 1 line of code, how can we help? Please elaborate your question. `IgeEntity` class? sort of 3rd party library?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor It says isogenic engine in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mouseUp, mouseOver and mouseOut functions:

```
MyShop.mouseUp(function() {
    alert('you clicked the shop'); 
    // show the stuff you want here
});

MyShop.mouseOver(function() {
    console.log('hovering the shop', MyShop);
    $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer'); // jQuery cursor CSS change on the body, 
                                       //  see how you handle custom images
});

MyShop.mouseOut(function() {
    console.log('no longer hovering the shop', MyShop);
    $('body').css('cursor', 'default'); 
});
```

You can also chain them.

etc... Can't help you more until you make your question clearer.